# Multiple predicates in ancestor xpath

Tags: xml, google-chrome, xpath

My XML file is like this:

```
<AllLogs>
   <Clubs>
      <Club id="a">
         <Name>Aa</Name>
         <City>Ab</City>
         <County>Ac</County>
      </Club>
      <Club id="b">
         <Name>Ba</Name>
         <City>Bb</City>
         <County>Bc</County>
      </Club>
      <Club id="c">
         <Name>Ca</Name>
         <City>Cb</City>
         <County>Ac</County>
      </Club>
   </Clubs>
   <Season Year="2015">
      <Skiers clubId="a">
         <Skier userName="andy">...</Skier>
      </Skiers>
      <Skiers clubId="a">
         <Skier userName="brad">...</Skier>
      </Skiers>
      <Skiers clubId="b">
         <Skier userName="gary">...</Skier>
      </Skiers>
      <Skiers clubId="c">
         <Skier userName="fred">...</Skier>
      </Skiers>
   </Season>
   <Skiers>
      <Skier userName="andy">...</Skier>
   </Skiers>
   <Skiers>
      <Skier userName="brad">...</Skier>
   </Skiers>
   <Skiers>
      <Skier userName="gary">...</Skier>
   </Skiers>
   <Skiers>
      <Skier userName="fred">...</Skier>
   </Skiers>
</AllLogs>
```

What I want to do is Find the skiers in the skier list (the nodelist of AllLogs/Skiers/Skier elements) who skied for an Ac-county club in the season of 2015.

Heres my XPath:

```
$x('./AllLogs/Skiers/Skier[../../Season[@Year="2015"] and ../../County="Ac"]', root)
```

I get as result all Skier nodes in the XML as opposed to the just the specific ones I want. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To get help you will need to provide enough XML to actually demonstrate the problem. Since your XML contains only one skier we can't possibly see what is happening.

Comment: Added some more elements now. Basically I get the nodelist of all 4 Skier elements instead of just 3 which skied for a club in Ac county.

Comment: You need to do an indirect lookup from `Skiers/@clubId` through `//Clubs/Club[@id]/County`.  If your context were XSLT this would be a simple `<key>` declaration but I'm not sure how to accomplish this in XPATH alone.

Comment: General joins aren't possible in XPath 1.0 (it is not "relationally complete", = equivalent to first-order predicate calculus). You haven't said which version of XPath you are using: in XPath 2.0 (or XQuery 1.0) it can be achieved using range variables.